# Reference a CocoaPod from a local Swift Package

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have an Xcode 11 iOS project where I have created a local Swift Package for some basic services.

I have also added CocoaPod support where I am using a CocoaPod (SwiftEntryKit) for some UI stuff in the main project (not the Swift Package) which works fine.

Now I would like to reference a new CocoaPod (SwifterSwift) from within the local Swift Package itself. Is this possible? It does not have access to the SwiftEntryKit Pod I am already using in the main project - if I import it, it does not know the modules.

If you cannot reference Cocoapods from a Swift Package it makes the package rather limiting.

Thanks.

Comment: I am running into the same issue. I love the new swift package architecture but I want to use a pod library from within my swift package.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am having the same issue @Derwrecked?

Comment: Never found a solution. I ended up not using the swift package architecture.

Comment: Could not find a solution. Ended up moving my local Swift package into the main code (therefore removing) so I could reference Pods.

Comment: Hello, any new solution for this issue?

Comment: any solution for using Cocoapods in swift package manager?